# txt file with FASTA data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, txt, fasta

I have a .txt file with amino acid sequences in FASTA format like this (it includes spaces between lines):

> Protein_A|maker-scaffold10x_349_pilon-augustus-gene-0.9
> MHIHIRFRPFDEYWKDVFASRIDTTKSLVKACEKLKLKFFINASAVGVVLAKDSNFIKSL
> YPSHRVGLGGALGSGQQWISWVHLDDVVRVVQFLIQPDCPVVSGPVNVTAPHAVRQAALS
> RCLSEAIGAPCLPFGAPPTPSFVPRLLLGPYRATLVLDGQRVIPQKLLDAGFQFKYALLE
> DALHAIYGRRPSPPAY*

> Protein_B|maker-scaffold10x_56_pilon-augustus-gene-0.90
> MNRLLPVLSSAVLTRCVLHVQLRTIFTARTISRYPFQSLCDLPVRWKSKSKGKVQTTVLA
> RDQLPSELLEVIRADEMKTSFEATLARFQSALQQKLALKITPQMLADLTIPEARAKLGQI
> ASLISQQEKHGASGQVTNQQLLIDLSARPHLVPAARKAVSQLLETTDHGSASSLIESAGQ
> AAFTIRLRTVVTREAREELIHKGQEMLNQVKREMDRIYQTHDKLIPNTPEGKKHHSEDHL
> FAAREYLRSVVKSNHALAATIWEKKHAELSGP*

I would like to import them into R studio in a dataframe:

```
Name                                                    Sequence
Protein_A|maker-scaffold10x_349_pilon-augustus-gene-0.9 MHIHIRFRPFDEYWKDVFASRIDTTKSLVKACEKLKLKFFINASAVGVVLAKDSNFIKSLYPSHRVGLGGALGSGQQWISWVHLDDVVRVVQFLIQPDCPVVSGPVNVTAPHAVRQAALSRCLSEAIGAPCLPFGAPPTPSFVPRLLLGPYRATLVLDGQRVIPQKLLDAGFQFKYALLEDALHAIYGRRPSPPA*            
Protein_B|maker-scaffold10x_56_pilon-augustus-gene-0.90 MNRLLPVLSSAVLTRCVLHVQLRTIFTARTISRYPFQSLCDLPVRWKSKSKGKVQTTVLARDQLPSELLEVIRADEMKTSFEATLARFQSALQQKLALKITPQMLADLTIPEARAKLGQIASLISQQEKHGASGQVTNQQLLIDLSARPHLVPAARKAVSQLLETTDHGSASSLIESAGQAAFTIRLRTVVTREAREELIHKGQEMLNQVKREMDRIYQTHDKLIPNTPEGKKHHSEDHLFAAREYLRSVVKSNHALAATIWEKKHAELSGP*
```

Which package could I use?

Comment: Searching google for "Read FASTR file in R" leads you directly to the `sequinr` package - have you tried that?  Did it meet your needs?

Comment: Try to use Biostrings package and functions like readDNAStringSet.